# Constant current density

Tags: voltage, current, current-measurement, current-limiting, constant-current

I am reading an article that says

> ... constant current density of \$−1.0\,\mathrm{A \cdot cm^{-2}}\$

Let's say that I have material that's \$2\,\mathrm{cm^{2}}\$, how would I calculate what's the actual current density that I need to use?

[image]

> Chronopotentiometry during Li electrodeposition performed at 
>   2.0, 1.0, 0.5, and 0.1 mA cm −2 in 1 M LiPF 6 1:1 EC/DMC. 
>   Soak time before plating was 1 hr. The onset time of dendritic Li electrodeposition, which coincides with the maximum in surface 
>   overpotential, decreases as the plating current density is increased.

Here's a link to the [research paper](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Chronopotentiometry-during-Li-electrodeposition-performed-at-20-10-05-and-01-mA-cm_fig3_328526780)

It's not homework, I am just reading trying to understand what's the meaning behind.

Constant current density of \$0.1\,\mathrm{mA \cdot cm^{-2}}\$
so I asked in a simple way so that I can figure out these measurements by myself.

So can anyone actually help me understand this without down voting the question?

Comment: 2 cm is not an area. What article? Use for what? Don't make us guess at what you are trying to actually ask.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. The statement "how would I calculate what's the actual current density that I need to use?" lacks specifics and is unclear. If the article you mention is available online, edit your question and provide article's URL and the exact text from the article. Also post whatever work you've done to this point to solve this problem yourself so that we can provide feedback on your work.  Otherwise, this question seems unanswerable because it is unclear what you are asking, and this is possibly a homework assignment, which means this question will likely be closed by the moderators.

Comment: It's an electrolysis problem; The electro-deposition paper. I've updated the question with a link to the URL, as well as here: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Chronopotentiometry-during-Li-electrodeposition-performed-at-20-10-05-and-01-mA-cm_fig3_328526780

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Current density is a parameter that is different for each of those colored lines in your graph.

If the current density you choose to use is \$\text {1mA/cm}^2\$then the  current through a \$\text{2cm}^2\$ conductor will be 2mA.

Comment: Tip: SE supports `<sup>...</sup>` and `<sub>...</sub>. It avoids breaking the flow with MathJAX.

Comment: @Transistor was editing on the fly— so tedious on this platform. I’ll look at sup

Comment: Maybe, but at least it's possible!

Answer (score 0):

At the start your question you state:

> .. constant current density of −1.0 A⋅cm<sup>−2</sup>
>
> Let's say that I have material that's 2 cm<sup>2</sup>, how would I calculate what's the actual current density that I need to use?

If you need a current density of −1.0 A⋅cm<sup>−2</sup> then the current density that you need is −1.0 A⋅cm<sup>−2</sup>.

If you are asking what *current* you need then that will be −1.0 A⋅cm<sup>−2</sup> * 2 cm<sup>2</sup> = -2 A.

At the bottom of the question you ask about "Constant current density of  0.1mA⋅cm<sup>−2</sup>" but it is not clear why.